How do you prove this statement: $\frac{5}{1\cdot2\cdot3}+\frac{7}{3\cdot4\cdot5}+\frac{9}{5\cdot6\cdot7}+\cdots =-1+3\ln\left(2\right)$
How can prove this statement with the help of this property :$\ln\left(1+x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}x^{n}}{n}$
What i did was, i found the general term i.e $t_{n}=\frac{\left(5+2n\right)}{n\cdot\left(n+1\right)\cdot\left(n+2\right)}$
further I tried doing partial  fraction: $\frac{\left(5+2n\right)}{n\cdot\left(n+1\right)\cdot\left(n+2\right)}$ =$\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{\left(n+1\right)}+\frac{C}{\left(n+2\right)}$
where i got A=$\frac{5}{2}/$,B=-3,C=$\frac{1}{2}$
then let us assume  $\frac{5}{1\cdot2\cdot3}+\frac{7}{3\cdot4\cdot5}+\frac{9}{5\cdot6\cdot7}+...\ \infty=S$
We know $\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}$
then if we assume x aprroaches to 1 i.e putting a limit then,
$\lim_{x \to 1}$ $\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\lim_{x \to 1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}$
so, S= $\lim_{x \to 1}$ $\left[\frac{5}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)-3\left\{\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)-x\right\}+\frac{1}{2}\left\{\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\}\right]$
$\implies $ S= $\lim_{x \to 1}$ $\left[\frac{5}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)-3\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+3\cdot x+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cdot x-\frac{x^{2}}{4}\right]$
$\implies $ S= $\lim_{x \to 1}$ [$0+3\cdot x-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^{2}}{4}]$
$\implies $ S= $\frac{9}{4}$
which simply doesnt match the RHS.
What is wrong in this?
Further, what can be the intuition to solve this kind of questions where the given question was a  solving question rather than a proving question.
I even tried to solve the given question with the help of binomial series but couldn't, is there a way to solve this question with the help of binomial series?
Any new intuition,ideas are accepted

The statement as written makes no sense. You cannot sum $\infty$. I guess you mean the limit of the partial sum ? If so, omit the $\infty$ sign

I think you are on the right track, but the general term is wrong, check that replacing by $n=1,2\cdot$ you dont get the correct sequence.

Your general term $t_n$ has the wrong denominator: $t_n = \frac{2n+5}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(2n+3)}$ when $n \geq 0$ (not $n \geq 1$). Its partial fraction decomposition is
$$
t_n = \frac{2}{2n+1} + \frac{-3}{2n+2} + \frac{1}{2n+3}.
$$
Break up the middle term into two terms ($-3 = -2 - 1$):
$$
t_n = \frac{2}{2n+1} - \frac{2}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{2n+2} + \frac{1}{2n+3},
$$
so
$$
t_n = 2\left(\frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{2n+3}\right).
$$
Write this as $t_n = 2u_n - v_n$. The series $\sum_{n \geq 0} u_n$ and $\sum_{n \geq 0} v_n$, when expressed as alternating series (both $u_n$ and $v_n$ are differences of successive reciprocals), are both closely related to the standard alternating series equal to $\ln 2$. Work out that relation by looking at the partial sums of the $u_n$'s and $v_n$'s for small values of $n$ to see what is going on. Then with a bit of work you'll get your desired result.

A comment has pointed out the mistake you have made during partial fraction decomposition. The answer of @KCd also reiterated the same point while proposing a good method to solve your problem. Here, we explain a slightly different way of approaching to prove your statement.
First, we express the given series using its $n^\text{th}$ term.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(3+2n\right)}{\left(2n-1\right) \left(2n\right)\left(n+2\right)}, \quad\text{where}\enspace n\ge1\tag{1}$$
It is given that,
$$\ln\left(1+x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(2n+1\right)}x^{n}}{n},\quad\text{where}\enspace -1\lt x\le 1.$$
When we substitute $x=1$, we get,
$$\ln\left(2\right)=\dfrac{1}{1}-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dots \space .$$
This can be expressed as the difference between two series as shown below.
$$\ln\left(2\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2n} \tag{2}$$
Now, we multiply (2) by 3 and substitute it from the given series (1) to obtain,
$$\small{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(3+2n\right)}{\left(2n-1\right) \left(2n\right)\left(n+2\right)}- 3\ln\left(2\right)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\left(3+2n\right)}{\left(2n-1\right) \left(2n\right)\left(n+2\right)}-\dfrac{3}{2n-1}+\dfrac{3}{2n}\right)}.\tag{3}$$
When the RHS of (3) is simplified it looks like
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(3+2n\right)}{\left(2n-1\right) \left(2n\right)\left(n+2\right)}- 3\ln\left(2\right)=- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{\left(2n-1\right) \left(2n+1\right)}.\tag{4}$$
So, we need only to prove the RHS of (4) is equal to $-1$. This is much easier than handling (1). Let us consider the partial fraction decomposition of the $n^\text{th}$ term of the RHS of (4).
$$\dfrac{2}{\left(2n-1\right) \left(2n+1\right)}=\dfrac{A}{2n-1}+\dfrac{B}{2n+1}$$
We have $A=1$ and $B=-1$. With that we can expand term by term to see what happens.
$$1^{\text{st}}\text{-term}\quad\dfrac{2}{1\times 3}=\color{red}{\dfrac{1}{1}}- \dfrac{1}{3}\qquad\qquad\quad$$
$$2^{\text{nd}}\text{-term}\quad\dfrac{2}{3\times 5}=\dfrac{1}{3}- \dfrac{1}{5}\qquad\qquad\quad$$
$$3^{\text{rd}}\text{-term}\quad\dfrac{2}{5\times 7}=\dfrac{1}{5}- \dfrac{1}{7}\quad\text{and so on}$$
When all the terms added, we are left with $1$. Therefore, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(3+2n\right)}{\left(2n-1\right) \left(2n\right)\left(n+2\right)}=3\ln\left(2\right)-1.$$
